# Unable to install mysql workbench on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, server, mysql, update-manager, repository

I am trying to install mysql but unfortunately, I can't do that. There is an error being shown in the terminal.
The command I used to update is :
`Sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community`, then
`Sudo apt install mysql-workbench`

The error shown is :

`E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench`.

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Install the MySQL Workbench package. There might be multiple Workbench packages available, so specify the exact version to install such as `mysql-workbench-community`.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

It might make you differ to `snap install mysql-workbench-community`

Comment: I tried it but this error is happening : ```Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "mysql-workbench-community", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install mysql-workbench-community"

E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench-community```

Comment: ok now type sudo snap install mysql-workbench-comunity let me know if that works its a snap package.

Comment: Glenix : sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community (with 2 m)